# What is the Twitter API rate limit when searching with tweet ids?

Tags: api, twitter, tweepy, rate-limiting

I am using Tweepy's `statuses_lookup()` to access some tweets by providing a list of 100k tweet ids and have a couple of questions.

Does the Twitter API rate limit apply to this scenario? And is there some risk that I lookup 100k tweets and then get charged afterwards or will the API just stop working when I eventually exceeds the limit?

This is my api decleration `api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)`.

Thanks for considering my question.

Answer (score 2):

180 calls every 15 minutes as per https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting.html

Comment: But I tried with 25k and it finished in 4-5 minutes, so it can't be that low. Even though I lookup 100 tweets in one API call, i. e. 180 calls is 180*100 = 18k tweets. That is what I don't understand about the Twitter rate limit.